# Gini coefficient and Lorenz curve for credit scoring data in R

Tags: r, rstudio, gini

I've got the problem with calculating Gini coefficient and drawing Lorenz curve in R for credit scoring data.

My raw data is in following columns: client number (Col A), scoring points (Col B), bad/good (0 - good or 1 - bad) (Col C).

Which package should I use and how to calculate Gini Index and draw Lorenz curve for my data?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to ask a better question please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ineq/index.html